Computer reset while VS Code remote debugging
While using VS Code to debug a remote Ubuntu Linux (apache2) web server/application, my Windows 11 PC resets on a seemingly random basis. No BSOD, no memory dump; just a black screen and a restart of the computer.
Here's what I've done so far:

disabled all non-essential VS Code Extensions (several are required for ssh remote debugging of a PHP/JS application)
performed a clean reinstall of Windows 11
upgraded/downgraded my AMD video drivers
disabled virtual memory/paging

The computer still resets from time to time (maybe every hour or two) while using VS Code to debug. The problem doesn't arise when VS Code isn't running.
I'm going to try to narrow the issue down by running a local (WAMP) server on the Windows PC--so there's no ssh/remote connection--but, in the meantime, has anyone else seen this behavior?
